# Change a part of each url

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a list of urls on the site, and i need to switch dots in every one of them, after home url.

```
<div class="collection-name">
      <a href="http://shop.something.net/collections/100-grams/a.s.a.p." title="100 Grams">/collections/madelinetosh/a-s.a.p.</a>
    </div>
<div class="collection-name">\
      <a href="http://shop.something.net/collections/2-stitches/a.s.a.p." title="2 Stitches"><i class="check-icon"></i> 2 Stitches</a>
    </div>
```

In this example, i need switch dots in a.s.a.p. to a-s-a-p

I'm very new to JQ so, here is the shame of my code that doesn't work

```
$("div.collection-name a").each(function(){
  console.log($("div.collection-name a").get(0))
$("div.collection-name a").each.href( $("div.collection-name a").get(0).pathname.replace('.', '-') );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked very in detail all your logic but take into account that default `replace` do it only for the first occurrence of the character. If you want to replace all, you need to use a regular expression like this one

```
pathname.replace(/\./g, '-');
```

**EDIT**

Taking a better look to your code, this is what you need to replace the dot by '-'

```
$("div.collection-name a").each(function(){
    var hrefArray = $(this).prop('href').split('/');
    for(var i = 3; i < hrefArray.length; i++) {
        hrefArray[i] = hrefArray[i].replace(/\./g, '-'); 
    }

    $(this).prop('href', hrefArray.join('/')); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zc693d4v/)

Comment: The regular expression `/./` matches every character.

Comment: yeah... that was one of the problems. doesn't change anything though

Comment: It actually removes all dots, including dots in home url.

Comment: @user3638287: is always a.s.a.p the word that you need to replace or you need to do it for any word containing dots?

Comment: any word containing dots in the part of the href that comes after home url